# Wordpress 4.5.3 & Visual Composer 4.12 - can't insert or change media

Tags: php, wordpress

I recently updated a WP Site to 4.5.3, which also then required me to update my VC to 4.12.

Everything is running as it should, I can still upload media to wordpress fine, however now if I want to insert media into a row background or single media, clicking the add media button does nothing.

Just wondering if anyone has encountered a similar issue.

Comment: hi jayF, you still find issue in that

Comment: check for any js errors in console!